# Como retirar o espaço de "4 980 Rafael" apenas entre números

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

Eu tenho uma String "4 980 Rafael" e eu gostaria de saber como vou retirar apenas os espaçoes que estão entre os numeros em shell script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dê uma olhada no código abaixo, remove o primeiro espaço em branco encontrado.

```
echo "4 980 Rafael" | sed '0,/[[:blank:]]/s/[[:blank:]]//'
```

`[[:blank:]]` é uma classe  POSIX regex que remove espaços em branco, tabs... para mais informações sobre essa classe, [regex posix](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

output:

> 4980 Rafael

A Regex utilizada funciona da seguinte forma:

```
0,/padrao/s/padrao/substituicao/
```

onde `padrao` é o que será substituído e `substituicao` é o que vai substituir, o `0` no início diz que é somente a primeira ocorrência.

Comment: Ele quer remover espaços apenas entre os números.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart vou corrigir a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Análogamente à resposta do @Mathias mas com `awk` inves do `sed`:

```
echo "4 980 Rafael" | awk '{sub(" ","")}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dá-me ideia que as respostas anteriores estão apenas a remover o primeiro espaço (onde quer que esteja) ou seja  `sed 's/ //'`

Proponho:

```
echo "...   4 434 Rafael" | sed -r 's/([0-9]) ([0-9])/\1\2/'
```

ou seja: substituir Num Num -> NumNum